# Electron js app not working after building

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, knex.js, electron-builder

i create small app with electron js and sqlite with knex 
it work purfuctyl when i run npm start  but when i try to build app in windows with electron-builder 
i have problem,the login form not working ,i activate developer mode and i don't have any error in console log ,i submit events with jQuery

> ```
> package.json
> ```

```
{
  "name": "olad-amtaia-water-manager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Gérer les factures d'eau d'une association villageoise",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "olad-amtaia-water-manager",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "NSIS",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "author": "Boutamente abdessamad",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "mssql": "^6.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "sessionstorage": "^0.1.0",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "knex": "^0.20.10",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mssql": "^6.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "sessionstorage": "^0.1.0",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "electron": "^8.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "knex": "^0.20.10",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

> login sumbmit

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new Object();
        formData.email = $(this).find('#login_email').val();
        formData.password = $(this).find('#login_password').val();
        ipcRenderer.send('login',formData);
    });
```

> databade connexion

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const dbPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'database.db')
var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath);


const knex = require("knex")({
    client: "sqlite",
    connection: {
        filename:  db.filename
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
});
```

Comment: This is not from the wrong build configuration.

Comment: Can you share with the current login screen after build?

Comment: And you can open the developerTools when you are creating the browserWindow

Comment: i edit post and add some code the current login screen is showed normal without any console error,i think the error is in database connexion

Comment: After pack then where is the database.db or created at?

Comment: The database is in root folder

Comment: i find the problem ,i fix it by add "asar": false, in build object but the code of application is open source not encrypted but is work ,now i want to find solution more practice

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"nsis": {
  "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
  "uninstallDisplayName": "app"
}
...  
"win": {
  "target": [
     "nsis"
  ]
}
...
```

I haven't seen my electron project in a while but what I learned and was the best option for me, it was to deploy the app in a virtual machine with windows and another with linux, so I could try like in "real" enviroments

Comment: Can you share more details. Pictures or anything

Answer (score 0):

i find the problem ,i fix it by add "asar": false, in build object but the code of application is open source not crypted but is work ,now i want to find solution more practice